# using R program got error from NASAPOWER data

Tags: r, rcurl

When I use the following code in R program, getting the following error.

```
> library(nasapower)
> daily_single_ag <- get_power(
+     community = "AG",
+     lonlat = c(151.81, -27.48),
+     pars = c("RH2M", "T2M", "PRECTOT"),
+     dates = c("1985-01-01", "1985-01-31"),
+     temporal_average = "DAILY"
+ )
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(x$url$url, handle = x$url$handle) : 
  Timeout was reached: [power.larc.nasa.gov] Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds
```

Code:

```
library(nasapower)
daily_single_ag <- get_power(
  community = "AG",
  lonlat = c(151.81, -27.48),
  pars = c("RH2M", "T2M", "PRECTOT"),
  dates = c("1985-01-01", "1985-01-31"),
  temporal_average = "DAILY"
)


daily_single_ag
```

Any idea how to solve this issue

Comment: Related possible duplicate post https://stackoverflow.com/q/54624278/680068

Answer (score 0):

Something is blocking HTTP communication with the server.

It could be your firewall software or your ISP

If you have a firewall or internet security software, try temporarily disabling it. If that doesn't help, ask your ISP if they are blocking.